# How to space-pad unicode string character in R?

Tags: r, printf

I am trying to pad a character with a space using `sprintf()` (but any base R alternative is would be fine).

It works as expected for letter `"a"` but for `"β"` it won't work:

```r
sprintf('% 2s', 'a')
#> [1] " a"
sprintf('% 2s', 'β')
#> [1] "β"
sprintf('% 3s', 'β')
#> [1] " β"
```

I guess it has to do with the fact that it takes two bytes (i.e., two sprintf's "characters") to represent the `"β"` string... but so, I could I change my code to make it work and pad with spaces in a way that `"β"` is understood as one character (i.e., one-visible character).

Comment: There are no ANSI and Unicode characters. The entire string uses a single encoding, in fact, all strings in an application have the same encoding. What you describe (1 byte vs 2 or more) is how the strings are encoded using a very specific encoding, UTF8. That `β` would use only a single byte in a Greek codepage, just as `ß` would in Latin1

Comment: This may well be system dependent (which we'd need to know). I seem to get the behaviour that you want by default on R 4.0.0/Win10/English_UK.

Comment: Windows is a Unicode OS. *All strings* are Unicode, which means all strings use at least two bytes. R has significant issues with encodings, not just Unicode. It simply didn't handle them at all when it was first released, assuming that all files and strings would be single-byte using the local machine's encoding. R and R Studio couldn't even display Unicode text. While that was fixed (slowly) in the language itself, some packages still can't handle files with different encodings.

Comment: On Windows, the default encoding for non-Unicode applications (and strings) comes from the user's locale. On Linux, the `LC_` env variables specify the encoding used by *all* applications on the machine or a specific shell. Most of the time, the encoding is `UTF8`, but sometimes it's not, which causes problems. On Mac, the `LC_` variables are set in at least two different places, which can be ... annoying

Comment: BTW you may have found *another* R bug. Which R version are you using? Have you tried upgrading? Since `β` was treated as 2 bytes but `a` as 1, it means that you aren't using Wiindows, and the system encoding is UTF8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string to native first.  This worked for me on Windows but not on https://rdrr.io/snippets/ which reports its .Platform$os.type as unix.

```
s <- 'β'; n <- 3 # inputs

sprintf("%*s", n, enc2native(s))  # or hard code the 3 and drop n
## [1] "  ß"
```

Alternately use `paste0` or `substring<-` with `strrep` or convert the string to X's, perform the `sprintf` and then convert back.  These worked on Windows and on https://rdrr.io/snippets/ .

```
# 2
paste0(strrep(' ', n - nchar(s)), s)
## [1] "  β"

# 3
`substring<-`(strrep(" ", n), n - nchar(s) + 1, n, s)
## [1] "  ß"

# 4
sub("X+", s, sprintf("%*s", n, strrep("X", nchar(s))))
## [1] "  β"
```

Comment: There should be no need for this in the first place. There's only one character. This is a bug

Comment: The `enc2native` solution doesn’t work on macOS/R 4.0 nor on Linux (nor would I intuitively expect it to).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Is there a simple explanation why?

Comment: @MartinGal `enc2native` shouldn’t have any effect on string literals, since the encoding of the literal is *already* the native encoding. It only makes a difference if the string was read from some other source (e.g. a file) using a different encoding. (*Maybe* Windows does something differently, no idea.)

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, On my Windows PC the encoding of `s` is UTF-8 but the encoding of `enc2native(s)` is latin1.